# Prove that $\|f\|_{X^*} = \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} |f(x)|.$

Tags: vector-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. Let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded linear functional. We define:
$$\|f\|_{X^*} = \sup_{x \in X \\ x \neq 0} \dfrac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|_X}$$
Prove that:

$$\|f\|_{X^*} = \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} |f(x)| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} |f(x)| = \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} f(x) = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} f(x).$$

Comment: Have you at least tried to prove any of these equalities or at least some inequalities between some of these quantities?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x\ne 0$ and $X$ be of finite-dimensional, if not then please comment.

Since $f$ is bounded linear functional  so, $$|f(x)|\le ||f||\cdot||x||\implies \sup_{||x|\le 1}|f(x)|\le ||f||.....(1)$$

Next, note that one of the definition of $\displaystyle||\cdot||_{X^*}$ is $||f||=\inf_{M\in \mathcal M}\{M\}$. Where $\mathcal M =\{M>0:|f(x)||\le M ||x||,\forall x\in X\}$.

Now, $|f(x)|=|f(\frac{x}{||x||}||x||)|=||x||\cdot|f(\frac{x}{||x||})|\implies f(\frac{x}{||x||})\in \mathcal M$

So, $||f||\le f(\frac{x}{||x||})$ for all nonzero $x\in X$. Hence, $||f||\le \sup_{||x||\le 1}|f(x)|.....(2)$, the norm of $x$ is omitted as the maximum is attained at $||x||=1$

So $(1),(2)$ gives the equality. Moreover, in every finite dimensional space, any two norms are equivalent [[Proof here]](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/equivalence-of-norms-in-a-finite-dimensional-linear-space), so this completes the proof. Hope it works.